# Firebase Cross-platform issue - .setAsync() is setting in 2 path destinations instead of just one

Tags: c#, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

I am using Firesharp for my app in c# winforms. This database is also connected to my ReactJS website which deals with the same information.

I have noticed that when I make `.SetAsync` calls to my app on the website and then log in to my Winforms app, my WinForms app will automatically perform the last action I did on my website to my database which is a `.setAsync()` action which adds some user information to a list of other user's information. Now it will not stop. Anytime I log on to my c# app, it runs it.

It makes me think there is a queue of orders in firesharp?

here is my react code. From what I can tell, it is nothing out of the ordinary:

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        var date = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY" )

        setError("")
        setLoading(true)

        // grab user info first then use that.
        await firebaseApp.database().ref("Users/" + currentUser.uid + "/UserData").on('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.val() != null) {
                setContactObjects({
                    ...snapshot.val()
                })

                firebaseApp.database().ref("Projects/" + projectGUIDRef.current.value + "/queueList/" + userIdRef.current.value).set({
                    "EntryTimeStamp": date + " " + moment().format("hh:mm:ss a"),
                    "IsSyncing": false,
                    "UserId": userIdRef.current.value,
                    "UserName": usernameRef.current.value,
                })
            }
        })

        history.push("/Demo")

        setLoading(false)
    }
```

here is my c# winforms code of where the code is executing. For some reason, when this executes, it also updates the `EntryTimeStamp` field of the react code and completely sets all the information even if I delete it. It also happens if I run `.set()`.

```
updateLastLogin2(authLink);

private async void updateLastLogin2(FirebaseAuthLink authLink)
        {
            IFirebaseConfig config = new FireSharp.Config.FirebaseConfig
            {
                AuthSecret = this.authLink.FirebaseToken,
                BasePath = Command.dbURL,
            };
            IFirebaseClient client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);

            string newDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            if (authLink.User.DisplayName.Contains(adUserId) && authLink.User.DisplayName.Contains(adUserId))
            {
                await client.SetAsync("Users/" + this.authLink.User.LocalId + "/UserData/DateLastLogin", newDateTime);
            }
        }
```

Any and all help is appreciated, I've been at this for a day and a half now.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used fire-sharp but this is my guess

You are calling `await firebaseApp.database().ref("Users/" + currentUser.uid + "/UserData").on('value'` in your react, and then in your Csharp you are calling `client.SetAsync("Users/" + this.authLink.User.LocalId` .

What happens is the both listeners are listening to each other and then causing a loop.

In that case it's probably better to use `once` instead of `on` if you are just using it once.

In cases where you cannot use `.once`, then you should use `.off` to turn off the listener once you are done.

```
firebaseApp.database().ref("Users/" + currentUser.uid + "/UserData").once('value'`
```

You also shouldn't be using `await` here since `ref().on` creates a listener, it doesn't return a promise.

You should also move `history.push("/Demo")` into your firebase database callback function so it's called after you have set data